# Слово "выпростать"

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

В некоторой литературе, в частности, у Алексея Толстого, мне попадалось слово "выпростать". Оно мне настолько резануло слух, что по отношению ко всему творчеству Толстого осталось неприятное чувство.
Что это за слово и есть ли оно вообще в русском языке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно, есть.
Тут, правда, есть одна тонкость. 
В основном, литературном значении слово сейчас почти не употребляется. А означает оно - высвободить (от одежды, одеял, бинтов, веревки и т.п.), какую-либо часть тела.
А употребляется же слово в основном как народное, просторечно-разговорное. Значение - освободить от содержимого, обычно - жидкого или сыпучего.

А что там у Толстого-то, цитатку можно?

Comment: Цитату не приведу - не помню уже. Но в "Аэлите", например, это слово употребляется сплошь и рядом.

Comment: @behemothus  Нашлась цитатка, правда, у Льва Николаевича: _Вот первые мои воспоминания. Я связан, мне хочется выпростать руки, и я не могу этого сделать._ http://rvb.ru/tolstoy/01text/vol_10/02edit/0267.htm